# Given the xPath, is it possible to highlight an element in JavaFX webView?

Tags: java, javascript, xpath, javafx, jsoup

I have a JavaFX UI where I type a URL and it loads the website in the WebView. There is a textfield where I will specify the xPath. If I press "Find" button, the corresponding element has to be highlighted in the web view. Is it possible using JavaFX or JavaScript or Jsoup?

```
find.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
                String xPath = xpath.getText();
                String website = null;
                if(url.getText()!=null || !url.getText().isEmpty())
                    if(url.getText().startsWith("http://"))
                        website = (url.getText());  
                    else
                        website = ("http://"+url.getText());
                System.out.println(website);
                try {
                    if(website!=null){
                        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(website).get();
                        System.out.println(doc.toString());
                        doc.select(xPath);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
```

I have tried using Jsoup, but doesn't seem to work. Jsoup is not mandatory, unless I succeed in highlighting the element in any way possible.

Answer (score 0):

As of Jsoup 1.8.3 (version of this writing), the select method expect a CSS selector not an xPath query.
This leaves you with two options:

#### Option 1

Turn your xpath into a CSS selector.

#### Option 2

Keep xpath and use another tool instead of Jsoup.